# Adding Localstorage item for unique IDs

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to know if its possible to use Javascript to set LocalStoarge for items to hide them.

The catch is they have unique IDs inside their ID attribute that gets generated so you have no idea what they might be but if you click the delete button it should set an item and hide it for that specific item with that specific ID:

[image: List of Messages]

```
<div class="'.$contact_id.'-chat" id="'.$contact_id.'">
 <button onclick="deleteChat(this)">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: LocalStorage is not hidden storage.

Comment: As far as I've understood, you want to allow a user to delete an item then add its unique id to localStorage to next time the user visits your page, the item should be visible. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Correct @LokendraSoni but item should stay hidden which is why I went with LocalStorage instead of SessionStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```html
<div class="1-chat" id="'.$contact_id.'">
  <button onclick="deleteChat('.$contact_id.')">X</button>
</div>
```

```js
window.onload = deleteChats();

function deleteChat(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none"
  let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deleted_items"));
  if(items){
    items.push(id);
  }
  else{
    items = [id];
  }
  localStorage.setItem("deleted_items",JSON.stringify(items));
}

function deleteChats(){
  const chats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deleted_items"));
  chats.map(chat => {
    document.getElementById(chat).display = "none";
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lokendra - this solution seems to be the best it also opens up the opportunity then to show those items again should someone messages again.

Answer (score 0):

[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/h26upg8e/8/) **check this out**

**hide all ids from localstorage**

```
window.onload = function() {
 allStorage().map(id => {
      $("#"+id).hide();
  })
}
```

**Get get all ids in localstorage**

```
 function allStorage() {
    var values = [],
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = keys.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        values.push( localStorage.getItem(keys[i]) );
    }
    return values;
}
```

**Get id from class, hide the div and set an item in localstorage**

```
$('.del').on('click', function(event) {
       $("#"+this.id).hide();
       window.localStorage.setItem("id"+this.id, this.id)
})
```